# Simple form php with checkbox

Tags: php, forms, contacts

Simple mail with checkbox newsletter - what i do wrong?
Everything is ok - send information exept checkbox
Please help

```
<?php
if ( isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['subject']) && isset($_POST['text']) && filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {


  $test = "/(content-type|bcc:|cc:|to:)/i";
  foreach ( $_POST as $key => $val ) {
    if ( preg_match( $test, $val ) ) {
      exit;
    }
  }
            $message .= "<strong>Client:</strong>" . strip_tags($_POST['name']) . ;
            $message .= "<strong>E-mail:</strong>" . strip_tags($_POST['email']) . ;
            $message .= "Newsletter" . strip_tags($_POST['newsletter']) ; 

            $to = 'aaa@gmailcom';   
            $subject = $_POST['subject'];
            $headers = "From: " . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n";
            $headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($_POST['req-email']) . "\r\n";
            $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";

            mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
?>
```

And html

```
 <label for="newsletter">
         <input type="checkbox"  id="newsletter" name="newsletter" value="Yes" checked> Subscribe
  </label>
```

Comment: What is it meant to do, and what is it currently doing? It seems like it should add the newsletter value onto the $message

Comment: It send e-mail with Client name and e-mail, i need information about checkbox state

Answer (score 0):

$_POST['newsletter']  will only exist if checkbox is selected.

You can try something like this

```
<?php
$info = "";
if(isset($_POST['newsletter'])){
    $info = "You want to receive the newsletter";
}
else{ $info = "You dont want the newsletter"; }

$message .= "Newsletter :" . $info ; 
?>
```

Hope this help
ps: Use var_dump($_POST) to debug your posted datas

Comment: Can you post result of var_dump($_POST); ?